# Extjs Datefield does not show calender in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, datefield

Hi i have following code which works fien in FF and IE, however when calender icon is clicked in chrome, the calender spans the whole screen and do not show any dates. Please help

Here is the code

```
newDDEform = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    formId: 'newDDEform',
    enableColumnMove: false,
    autoScroll: Ext.isGecko ? false : true, // true if IE
    monitorValid: true,
    frame: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Form',
            width: 117,
            name: 'form_id',
            readOnly: true,
            value: formId
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Rev',
            width: 117,
            name: 'revision',
            readOnly: true,
            value: rev
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Site',
            name: 'site_id',
            id: 'site_id',
            width: 117,
            readOnly: true,
            value: siteId
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Specimen ID',
            name: 'subject_id',
            id: 'subject_id',
            width: 117,
            allowBlank: false
        },
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Visit Date',
            name: 'visit_dt',
            id: 'visit_dt',
            format: 'M-d-Y',     // Mon-dd-yyyy
            autoHeight: true,
            width: 117,
            allowBlank: false,
            maxLength: 11
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Visit#',
            name: 'visit_nbr',
            id: 'visit_nbr',
            width: 117,
            allowBlank: false
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Sequence',
            name: 'seq_nbr',
            id: 'seq_nbr',
            width: 117,
            allowBlank: false
        }
    ],      // end of panel items
    buttons: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Submit',
            id: 'submitbutton',
            formBind: true,
            handler: processAddDDEform
        }
    ]
});          // end of panel 

newDDEformWindow = new Ext.Window({
    animateTarget: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 260,
    width: 260,
    id: 'newDDEformWindow',
    plain: true,
    resizable: true,
    title: 'Add New DDE Visit Form',
    items: newDDEform
});
```

Comment: What version of ExtJS is this?

Comment: Extjs3.4 and chrome 28

Comment: This works fine for me in Chrome 28 and ExtJS 3.4 http://jsfiddle.net/ydJud/

Comment: Figured it out . You have to place following in ext-all.css or your style sheet

.x-date-picker{border:1px solid #1b376c;border-top:0 none;background:#fff;position:relative;width:117px

thanmks for your help, teh code is also using  extjs 2.0 as well

Answer (score 2):

Add the behind code into you stylesheet .
Maybe it works.

```
.x-date-menu {
   width: 175;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't do it like [Woody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2706635/woody) said, I did it like this:

```
table.x-date-inner {
   width:200px !important;
}
```